# PHP- Output from 2 different databases in 1 table

Tags: javascript, php, database, html-table, output

I'm currently trying to add an search function to something.
Everything is working just fine. The only Problem I have is that I want some hidden values that it searches for, these are in a different Database. I've got it to select, but it doesn't output correctly (See Screenshots below)

So there is an Customers Database, which have their First Name,last name and birthdate in. With that i select the "EK-Number" From the Contracts, The EK-Number is an unique ID Witch tells me what vehicle he bought. With That EK-Number I go to the Vehicle list and let him select the specific Vehicle. The only Problem I have is that he doesn't select the specific Vehicle from the Customer.

[image: Screenshot]

Translations:
Kunden - Customers
Fahrzeugverkauf -  Vehicle database
Kaufverträge  Contracts

My PHP Code (Don't cry please, I know its bad at first point, but it's just for testing at the moment) :

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped">
<?php


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Kunden`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<tr><th>Nachname</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Geburtsdatum</th><th>Straße</th><th>PLZ</th><th>ORT</th><th>E-Mail</th><th>Tel-NR</th><th>Bearbeiten</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $vorname = $row["Vorname"];
          $nachname = $row["Nachname"];
      $geb = $row["GebDatum"];

         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Nachname"]. "</td> <td>" . $row["Vorname"]. "</td><td>" . $row["GebDatum"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Strasse"]. "</td><td>" . $row["PLZ"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Ort"]. "</td><td>" . $row["EMail"]. "</td><td>" . $row["TelNr"]. "</td><td><a href='kunden_bearbeiten.php?id=$row[KdNr]&nachname=$row[Nachname]&vorname=$row[Vorname]&geb=$row[GebDatum]&strasse=$row[Strasse]&plz=$row[PLZ]&ort=$row[Ort]&mail=$row[EMail]&Notizen=$row[Notizen]&telnr=$row[TelNr]&vk=$row[VKNR]'>Bearbeiten</a></td></tr>";

     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
?>
    </center>

    <?php


        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `kaufvertraege` WHERE Vorname = '$vorname' and Nachname = '$nachname' and Geb = '$geb'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $eknr = $row["EkNr"];
            }

        }
?>
    <table class="table table-striped">
            <?php
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Fahrzeugverkauf` WHERE EKNR = $eknr";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "<tr><th>EK-NR</th><th>VK-Nummer</th><th>EK-Datum</th><th>RG-Nummer</th><th>Marke</th><th>Modell</th><th>Farbe</th><th>EZ</th><th>Motor-Nummer</th><th>FIN</th><th>KM</th><th>VK</th><th>EK-Brutto</th><th>EK-Netto</th><th>VK-Datum</th><th>Bearbeiten</th></tr>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" .$row["EKNR"].  "</td><td>" .$row["VKNummer"].  "</td><td>" . $row["EKDatum"]. "</td> <td>" . $row["RGNummer"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Marke"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Modell"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Farbe"]. "</td><td>" . $row["EZ"]. "</td><td>" . $row["MotorNr"]. "</td><td>" . $row["FIN"]. "</td><td>" . $row["KM"]. "</td><td>" . $row["VK"]. "</td><td>" . $row["EKBrutto"]. "</td><td>" . $row["EKNetto"]. "</td><td>" . $row["VKDatum"]."</td><td><a href='fahrzeuge_bearbeiten.php?id=$row[EKNR]'>link</a></td></tr>";
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Kunden`";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        echo "<tr><th>Nachname</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Geburtsdatum</th><th>Straße</th><th>PLZ</th><th>ORT</th><th>E-Mail</th><th>Tel-NR</th><th>Bearbeiten</th></tr>";
                        // output data of each row
                        while($vk = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                            $vorname = $row["Vorname"];
                            $nachname = $row["Nachname"];
                            $geb = $row["GebDatum"];

                            echo "<tr><td>" . $vk["Nachname"]. "</td> <td>" . $vk["Vorname"]. "</td><td>" . $vk["GebDatum"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Marke"]. "</td><td>" . $vk["PLZ"]. "</td><td>" . $vk["Ort"]. "</td><td>" . $row["EMail"]. "</td><td>" . $row["TelNr"]. "</td><td><a href='kunden_bearbeiten.php?id=$row[KdNr]&nachname=$row[Nachname]&vorname=$row[Vorname]&geb=$row[GebDatum]&strasse=$row[Strasse]&plz=$row[PLZ]&ort=$row[Ort]&mail=$row[EMail]&Notizen=$row[Notizen]&telnr=$row[TelNr]&vk=$row[VKNR]'>Bearbeiten</a></td></tr>";

                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Yes, because you are looping through the Kunden table for a second time, but you are referencing $row['Marke'], which somes from the Fahrzeugverkauf table. I think you need to either correct the variable ($row -> $vk) or build a better MySQLi query, using JOINs.

Comment: Alright I'll try it out. Thanks 4 the Tipp :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you are looping through the `Kunden` table for a second time, but you are referencing `$row['Marke']`, which somes from the `Fahrzeugverkauf` table. I think you need to either correct the variable (`$row` -> `$vk`) or build a better MySQLi query, using `JOIN`